# How to assign SortableBindingList to LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I just downloaded the [SortableBindingList](http://www.timvw.be/2008/08/02/presenting-the-sortablebindinglistt-take-two/) and I'm trying to assign it to this LINQ query (instead of var):

```
var q = from r in document.Descendants("release")
                        select new
                        {
                            Release = r.Attribute("id").Value,
                            Artist = String.Join(";", r.Element("artists").Descendants("artist").Select(x => x.Element("name").Value).ToArray()),
                            Album = r.Element("title").Value
                        };
```

It's probably not that hard, but I'm just really confused about how to do this... 
Some help will be appreciated!

**EDIT**

Static class:

```
public static class LINQExtension
{
    public static SortableBindingList<object> ToSbl(this IEnumerable<object> items)
    {
        return new SortableBindingList<object>(items);
    }
}
```

Assignment:

```
   SortableBindingList<object> sbl = LINQExtension.ToSbl(q);
   releases_dataGridView.DataSource = sbl;
```

Answer (score 3):

Because you're using an anonymous type, you need to create it using type inference:

```
public static SortableBindingList<T> ToSbl(this IEnumerable<T> items) {
    return new SortableBindingList<T>(items);
}

var sbl = (...).ToSbl();
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer, I've got the sorting to work, although I'm not sure if it's exactly what you mean. I've edited my posted so you can see it.

Comment: You're losing all type inference.  If you don't want type inference, you don't need an extension at all; you can just write `new SortableBindingList<object>(q)`.  If you do want type inference, just declare the variable using `var`.